# How to populate one extra property in a .Select - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, dto

I'm using my `Map` method to create `DTO` object from my context class `Company` and it looks like this:

```
private CompDTO Map(Company company)
{
    return new CompDTO()
    {
        Id = company.Id,
        Title = company.Title,
        ParentCompanyId = company.ParentCompanyId,
    };
}
```

`CompDTO` looks like this:

```
public class CompDTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public long? ParentCompanyId { get; set; }
    public bool HasChildrens { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using it like this, basically receiving list of companies and calling another `Map` method which would create `DTO` object from my company objects and main issue for me is that `Company` class `does not contain` `HasChildrens` property, so I have to populate it somehow, and I couldn't do it where I'm maping other props because there I dont have access to a companies list.

```
private IEnumerable<CompDTO> Map(IEnumerable<Company> companies)
{
    // Mapping all properties except HasChildrens because it does not exist in Company object so I decided to map it later

    var result = companies.Select(c => Map(c));

    // Here I wanted to return all previously mapped objects + I would like to add to each object HasChildren property, but obliviously my syntax is not good:

    return result.Select(c => new { c, c.HasChildrens = companies.Any(cc => cc.ParentCompanyId == c.Id) });
}
```

I'm retrieving error:  *Invalid anonymous type declarator*.

I've tried to add HasChildrens like this also:

```
return result.Select(c => {c.HasChildrens = companies.Any(cc => cc.ParentCompanyId == c.Id)});
```

But still issues..

Basically I simply want to add `HasChildrens` for each my Mapped `DTO` and return it **as it was added in Map method.**

Any kind of help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The return type of your method `private IEnumerable<CompDTO> Map(IEnumerable<Company> companies)` is `IEnumerable<CompDTO>`

So the issue is that you're returning an anonymous type rather than the expected `CompDTO`

Change `return result.Select(c => new { ... }`

to

```
return result.Select(c => new CompDTO { 
    Id = ...
    Title = ...
    ParentCompanyId = ...
    HasChildrens = ...
})
```

EDIT:

The actual question is:

**How do I set the property HasChildrens in the CompDTO while converting from db classes to dto classes**

I'd say that the most common way to solve that is to pass in the value while converting:

```
private CompDTO Map(Company company, bool hasChildrens) {
    return new CompDTO()
    {
        Id = company.Id,
        Title = company.Title,
        ParentCompanyId = company.ParentCompanyId,
        HasChildrens = hasChildrens
    };
}
```

You could also iterate the result after the fact and set the HasChildrens like so: (I wouldn't recommend this)

```
foreach(dto in result) {
   dto.HasChildrens = ...
}
```

You could also insert the logic of obtaining the HasChildrens value inside of the Map method: (I wouldn't recommend this either)

```
private CompDTO Map(Company company, IEnumerable<Company> companies) {
    return new CompDTO()
    {
        Id = company.Id,
        Title = company.Title,
        ParentCompanyId = company.ParentCompanyId,
        HasChildrens = companies
                       .Any(c => c.ParentCompanyId == company.Id) 
    };
}
```

Comment: but I don't want to repeat all new CompDTO again, I just want to add HasChildrens because other properties were added before. :)

Comment: My answer mainly addresses your error message 'Invalid anonymous type declarator.'.

If you want to set the HasChildrens property when converting from your database class to your dto class. Then I would just pass that value into the constructor of the DTO.

You could also just add your `HasChildrens = companies.Any(cc => cc.ParentCompanyId == c.Id)` inside of your Map method.. albeit a bit of a code smell

Comment: that led to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259143/how-to-solve-npgsql-npgsqloperationinprogressexception-a-command-is-already-in