# LINQ - For each item in select populate value to one unpopulated property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, ienumerable

I'm using my `Map` method to create `DTO` object from my context class `Company` and Mapping looks like this:

```
private CompDTO Map(Company company)
{
    return new CompDTO()
    {
        Id = company.Id,
        Title = company.Title,
        ParentCompanyId = company.ParentCompanyId,
    };
}
```

`CompDTO` looks like this:

```
public class CompDTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public long? ParentCompanyId { get; set; }
    public bool HasChildrens { get; set; }
}
```

Here's how I'm calling my Map method :

```
private IEnumerable<CompDTO> Map(IEnumerable<Company> companies)
{

    var result = companies.Select(c => Map(c));

     return result.Select(c => { c.HasChildrens = companies.Any(cc => cc.ParentCompanyId == c.Id)});
 }
```

After main mapping I'm trying to populate `HasChildrens` property in my `return result.Select` for each `compDTO` item.

But it doesn't work cuz it says:
[image]

But I guess there's more deeper issue because I added simply test like this:

```
return result.Select(c => { c.HasChildrens = true; });
```

And it said:*The type arguments for method cannot be infered from usage.*

Any kind of help would be awesome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate one extra property in a .Select - LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256008/how-to-populate-one-extra-property-in-a-select-linq)

Comment: Avoid posting the same question twice or more, please.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Previous question was deleted before..

Comment: Ok, but unless you have a real reason, you can edit it.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I deleted previous question because it was pretty similar, this is the only question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEnumerable Select is supposed to create a new sequence from the input. If you want to just change a property using Select as it were a foreach then you need to return the object passed to your lambda

```
 return result.Select(c => 
               { 
                   c.HasChildrens = companies.Any(cc => cc.ParentCompanyId == c.Id);
                   return c;
               });
```

But do you really prefer this approach to a simple For Loop? I find this more clear

```
foreach(Company c in result)
    c.HasChildrens = companies.Any(cc => cc.ParentCompanyId == c.Id);

return result;
```

Comment: Sir, after adding this how is possible it says  `$exception{"A command is already in progress: SELECT t.id,name, etc, etc  FROM companies AS c\r\n etc. etc Npgsql.NpgsqlOperationInProgressException` .. I mean how come, we'r not accessing context again?